# Identify read logs from log buffer in Android programmatically

Tags: android, logging, runtime, logcat

I have a program to read logs and based on certain filters save logs to database.

```
private static final String LOGCAT_EVENTS_CMD = "logcat -b events -v time";
try { 
        EventProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(LOGCAT_EVENTS_CMD);
        BufferedReader eventBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                EventProcess.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = eventBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            onLogFetched(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But sometimes android kills my application and my application restarts automatically `START_STICKY`. In this case already read logs are read again and again saved to database.

I want a piece of code which will restrict/identify already read logs.

For clearing the log buffer in android we have command as:-

```
adb logcat -c
```

And also I can't clear log buffer before start of process as it will clear logs which was not recorded.(logs generated between kill of App and start of App/Monitoring log Process)